# Forking a process into 7 children without looping

Tags: c, operating-system

How can I create 7 processes using 1 parent in just 3 `forks()` calls? Looping is not allowed out of 7 1 is the parent one

Comment: Fork three times, but only do the last fork if the process has been the parent (or child) the first two times (find that out by looking at the return value and seeing if it is non-zero).

Comment: You mean: *parent* only is allowed to fork three times? Because for 6 children in total you need 6 forks in total...

Comment: I think what he means is that it starts out with one parent and then the code can contain three calls to `fork()`.

Answer (score 3):

I tried

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("master process is %d.\n", getpid());
    fork();
    fork();
    fork();
    wait(0);
    printf("my pid is %d; my parent pid is %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    return 0;
}
```

and got the output

```
master process is 28982.
my pid is 28982; my parent pid is 31294
my pid is 28985; my parent pid is 28982
my pid is 28984; my parent pid is 28982
my pid is 28983; my parent pid is 1
my pid is 28986; my parent pid is 28984
my pid is 28988; my parent pid is 28983
my pid is 28987; my parent pid is 1
my pid is 28989; my parent pid is 28987
```

Comment: Adding getppid to show the parent would be nice. +1 anyway

Comment: What is the `wait(0)` for?

Comment: @Ctx: I just use it LOL ... anyway, I tried without and all forked process reported parent pid of 1

Comment: @pmg Correct, when the parent exits then the children drop to ppid 1. So the `wait()` fulfills indeed a purpose when the parent pid is needed.

Comment: @Aconcagua: one of the processes (identifiable with the new change) is the *master* process; the process ultimately initiated by the shell when I called the executable

Comment: @Aconcagua: good question :-)  The three `fork()`s _create_ 7 _new_ processes, leaving 8 in total... if the specification is supposed to read 6 _new_ processes, leaving 7 in total, then the original parent needs to avoid the third `fork()` -- hoho.

Comment: @ChrisHall Oh, didn't pay attention (once more...) 7 *children*, not seven processes in total. Actually, I was fully aware of the parent being a further process ;).

Comment: @ChrisHall But isn't explicitly stated in the question that _out of 7 1 is the parent one_ ?

Comment: @Karim Hm... If so, then my original comment was right (to bad then, shouldn't have deleted it...).

Comment: @Karim... OP's question is badly formulated. If the *master* process **creates** 7 new processes there will be a total of 8 processes; to have a total of 7 processes you must create only 6 children

Comment: @Karim: perhaps... it starts by saying "create 7"... the "out of 7 1 is the parent one" at the end, can be read to qualify what is meant by "create".  So, I think the real lesson here is the importance of clear specifications :-)

Comment: `#if TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES == 7 if(getpid() == master) #elif TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES != 8 #error TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES not defined or invalid #endif { fork(); }`...

Answer (score 0):

Total number of processes created using fork() can be found using **2^n** where **n is the number of times fork() is being called**. Here if we calls fork() 3 times, then **2^3** processes will be created i.e **8**.